# ChangeDetection on child element with OnPush strategy

Tags: angular, validation, rxjs, angular-forms

I have an `InputComponent` which works as a wrapper around several native inputs and adds some logic.

This component has an input `control` which accepts `FormControl` and binds it to the input field via `[formControl]`.

To improve the performance I've set `changeDetectionStrategy` to OnPush.

Now I've noticed that when I use `formGroup.get(...).setValidators(...)` the InputComponent doesn't update its state. How can I perform this? I don't see any hook into validators change cycle.

As a workaround I've added a public API to manually invoke `detectChanges()`.

Is there an Observable that I can listen to and call `detectChanges()` when there is changes to validation rules and not to cause call stack size exceed.

---

This can be paraphrased as **How can I invoke a change detection of the whole tree when OnPush detection strategy is being used**

---

Small [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrokpb) here you can see one checkbox. Click the button and see that there is no difference. However, If you click on checkbox it will show an asterisk.

What's also interesting is that when `requiredTrue` is assigned to control and the control doesn't have `true` as a value the form is still valid. I can't understand why.

Comment: Why would `detectChanges` cause stack overflow?

Comment: I suggest that `detectChanges` may cause some form re-evaluation and thus create a stack overflow.

Comment: Would it be possible to see a minimal working example e.g. as a stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue here is that setting the validators outside breaks the concept of immutability. The input you have is an object where only a property inside that object is changed. Angular doesn't register this as a change.

So interestingly this is not just a problem with ChangeDetction.OnPush. Using the default change detection, angular does update the view because all components get checked, but if you would register to the onChanges lifecycle hook, you would notice that the actual change is not registered inside the lifecycle hook in either change detection configuration. So be careful it only seems to work with the default change detection, but isn't working completely. Therefore be careful to keep object mutability in mind independent on the change detection you are using.

---

Having said that: In your case, following SoC, I would actually move setting the validator inside the input component, dependent on a boolean input property instead of setting the validator from outside. Next to SoC this would also have the advantage that in case there are other validators your input component might need, you actually have all those in one spot and could reset those once you only want to remove the required validator since it as far as I know there is no possibility of removing a specific validator (yet).

Your `input.component.ts` would look something like this (be aware this is only pseudo code):

**input.component.ts**

```
export class InputComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() required: boolean;
  @Input() control: FormControl;

  ngOnChanges(simpleChanges: SimpleChanges){
    if(simpleChanges.required) {
      if(simpleChanges.required.nextValue) {
        this.control.addValidator(...)
      } else {
        this.control.clearValidators()
      }
    }
  }

}
```

---

In case setting the validator inside your input is not at all an option for whatever reason, you would actually need to trigger the changeDetection manually. For this I would do the following:

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  toggleValidator() {
    if (this.requiredTrue) {
      this.requiredTrue = false;
      this.formGroup.get('agreed').clearValidators();
      // this is important
      this.formGroup.get('agreed').updateValueAndValidity();
    } else {
      this.requiredTrue = true;
      this.formGroup.get('agreed').setValidators(Validators.requiredTrue)
      // this is important
      this.formGroup.get('agreed').updateValueAndValidity();
    }

    console.log(this.formGroup);
  }
```

**input.component.ts**

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.ref.markForCheck();
      });
  }
```

Have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxt7hi)

Comment: The idea around `valueChanges` is cool (I've been thinking of playing around state change), however I don't understand why you are using `markForCheck` instead of `detectChanges` and why it actually works, because there is an asynchronous task is required to trigger change detecting after this "mark"

Comment: Angular calls detectChanges itself. With markForCheck you only tell angular that there is a change which needs to be considered during the next changeDetection cycle. If you use ChangeDetection.OnPush and you are changing a component property inside a subscription you always need to call markForCheck otherwise that change is not projected template.